# QT moc class can not find the original file, despite it being in correct directory

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, path, mocking

I'm trying to build qt project but I keep getting error about no existing header in moc object moc_SerialPortManager.cpp. I moved with bash to that directory and used cd cmd with the path written in mock object and it leads to the correct directory. Does anybody have a slightest idea how to resolve it? At this point it's quite big project so just please tell me what could I publish to make this easier for you?
I have it all on git https://github.com/Orpiczy/AcornScanner/compare/fronAndBackJoin if you wish to check it out

I'm using Mingw compiler 8.1.0 64-bit for c++ and Qt 6.2.0, I'm working on windows10

**moc_SerialPortManager.cpp**

```
#include <memory>
#include "../../../../../../source/controllers/LowLevelFunctionality/DeviceController/ProfilometerManager/SerialPortManager.hpp"
#include <QtCore/qbytearray.h> ...
```

**logs**
E:\Dokumenty\AiR_rok_4\S7\EngineeringThesis\AcornScanner\cm\cm-lib\build\windows\gcc\x64\debug.moc\moc_SerialPortManager.cpp:10: error: ../../../../../../source/controllers/LowLevelFunctionality/DeviceController/ProfilometerManager/SerialPortManager.hpp: No such file or directory
........\AcornScanner\cm\cm-lib\build\windows\gcc\x64\debug.moc\moc_SerialPortManager.cpp:10:10: fatal error: ../../../../../../source/controllers/LowLevelFunctionality/DeviceController/ProfilometerManager/SerialPortManager.hpp: No such file or directory
#include "../../../../../../source/controllers/LowLevelFunctionality/DeviceController/ProfilometerManager/SerialPortManager.hpp"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the layout of your repository differs from your local filesystem:

```
.../debug/.moc/
```

vs.

```
.../debug.moc/
```

Therefore the relative path steps up one level too much and results in a non-existing path.

It is generally considered bad practice to put automatically generated files (i.e. moc files) under version control. I would assume if you remove the whole `build` directory and build again you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for advice, it's my first time really getting into working with git that's why I skipped .gitignore. About the isssue -> I had moved my project from one folder to another and shadow build kept compiling in old location that's why it didn't work.  I just changed it in project settings : )

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works now. If the answer solves your problem you can consider setting it to "accepted".